# When exceeding the number of characters, mark with ... at the end

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to know if it would be possible when exceeding the number of characters to return  `...` at the end?

I have this code, but it always leaves the characters on the same line, I would like it to have a maximum of two columns and put it at the end.

I am using Bootstrap.

https://jsfiddle.net/leonardo180360/f79yajps/4/#&togetherjs=cl3Vilbtx6

```css
.teste {
  max-width: 30ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h6 class=" teste">Ração Premier Cães Adultos Pequeno Porte Frango & Salmão 2,5 kg</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you upload an image showing the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have multiple lines when you've used the `white-space: nowrap` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` declarations. `white-space: nowrap` prevents wrapping in any form.